# How to add new widget in GridLayout without resizing older widgets?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I have added GridLayout to ScrollView, and I'm adding widgets in GridLayout dynamically from python program.Instead of using more space of window it's resizing height of older widgets.What am i doing wrong here?

I tried putting BoxLayout inside GridLayout but it's not working.
I also tried to add widgets directly to ScrollView but i found out ScrollView only supports one widget.

My kv code:

```
<Downloading>:
    my_grid: mygrid
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        size_hint_y : None
        hight: self.minimum_height
        id: mygrid
```

My python code:

```
class Downloading(ScrollView):
    set_text = ObjectProperty()
    my_grid = ObjectProperty()

    def __init__(self, select, link, path, username, password):

        self.select = select
        self.link = link
        self.path = path
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.p_bar = []
        self.stat = []

        self.parent_conn, self.child_conn = Pipe()

        p = Process(target=main, args=(self.child_conn, self.select,
                                       self.link, self.path,
                                       self.username, self.password))
        p.start()

        super().__init__()

        self.event = Clock.schedule_interval(self.download_GUI, 0.1)

    def newFile(self, title):
        # self.newId = "stat" + str(len(self.p_bar) + 1)
        self.stat.append(Label(text=''))
        self.p_bar.append(ProgressBar())
        self.my_grid.add_widget(Label(text=title))
        self.my_grid.add_widget(self.stat[-1])
        self.my_grid.add_widget(self.p_bar[-1])

    def download_GUI(self, a):

        temp = self.parent_conn.recv()

        print(temp)

        if temp == "new":
            self.downloading = True
            return
        if self.downloading:
            self.newFile(temp)
            self.downloading = False
            return
        if type(temp) == type({}):
            self.complete = temp['complete']
            if not self.complete:
                status = "{0}//{1} @ {2}  ETA: {3}".format(temp['dl_size'],
                                                      temp['total_size'],temp['speed'],temp['eta'])
                self.stat[-1].text = status
                self.p_bar[-1].value = temp['progress']
                return

        if temp == "end":
            self.event.cancel()
            Clock.schedule_once(exit, 3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you just need to set the height for each widget that you add to your `GridLayout`. For example:

```
    self.my_grid.add_widget(Label(text=title, size_hint=(1, None), height=50))
```

You might need to do the same for the other widgets you are adding. The `GridLayout` may give the initially added widgets more space than that, but will not squeeze them any any tighter than your specified `height`.

Comment: After adding initial height GridLayout isn't squeezing previous widget but after overflow Scrollview isn't working anymore.

Comment: You have a typo in your `kv` file: `hight:` should be `height:`

Answer (score 0):

After applying following changes to kv file

```
<Downloading>:
    size: self.size
    my_grid: mygrid
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        size_hint_y : None
        row_default_height: '25dp'
        row_force_default: True
        id: mygrid
```

And adding this line in the end of constructor (`__init__`), it is working as expected.

```py
self.my_grid.bind(minimum_height=self.my_grid.setter('height'))
```